# integrate radio button list item with text box

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have already a radio button and i need to add radio button followed by text box 
please help me to integrate this(in aspx page)
the html content is like 
[image: html example image]Other `

Comment: Please post the code for what you've done so far

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].